# Magento addAttribute to a specific product tab (admin)

Tags: php, magento, module, attributes, admin

Is it possible to use the addAttribute function to add an attribute directly to a specific product new & edit tab? For example the price tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just specify the tab by attribute 'group':

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_custom_product_attr',
    array(
        ...
        'group' => 'Tab XY',
        ...
    ));
```

You may also want to order your attribute inside the tab. You can do this by specifying the attribute position:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_custom_product_attr',
    array(
        ...
        'group' => 'Tab XY',
        'position' => Z
        ...
    ));
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the hint.. If someone is interested in setting the order for the new Attribute: 'position' => 5

Comment: Glad it worked. Thanks for the info about position. I'll add it to my answer.